# Declare implemented IEnumerable of an interface or of a class as obsolete

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings

Is it possible to declare the derived or implemented IEnumerable-part of an interface or of a class as obsolete whereas the rest of the class or interface still is current? How do I declare this?

```
interface Foo : IEnumerable<Bar>{

    int SomethingNonObsolete{
         get;
    }

}
```

In the above examble, I would like that using the iterators of the implemented IEnumerable leads to a compiler-obsolete-warning whereas the use of the interface itselfs or the use of the `SomethingNonObsolete`-Property does not lead to such a warning.

The following code **should lead** to a compiler-obsolete warning

```
foreach(var bar in myFooImplementingInstance){
```

The following code **should not lead** to a compiler-obsolete warning

```
myFooImplementingInstance.SomethingNonObsolete.ToString()
```

**UPDATE**
Because there are many answers but every answer only concerns about a part of the problem, here a summary and a final statement:

In the end, it’s technically not possible because of LINQ.

If one will use it anyway, as Panda shows in his answer, it’s easy done for classes. Declare the enumerators as obsolete and your fine.

```
[Obsolete]
IEnumerator<Bar> GetEnumerator()
[Obsolete]
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
```

For interfaces, it can be done in a similar way, as Bozhidar remarks in a comment. Declare the enumerator with the new-keyword and mark it as obsolete.

```
[Obsolete]
new IEnumerator<ITabularDataRow> GetEnumerator();
```

However, while both of these versions do in general what they are supposed to, they both break when using LINQ. 
Therefore, the answer seems to be that it is not possible in a comprehensive way and that this is in most cases for good (see answer and comments from MDeSchaepmeester).

Comment: So you basically want to delete the interface from your API? Why not create a new class that does not implement the interface?

Comment: No, I want to remove the IEnumerable from the interface, but I currently can not do it because many applications rely on the interface. I want to prevent developers of using the foreach on the IENumerable in new code so that in the future it will be easier to remove and we have not even more references.

Comment: There is a way to do this with the **exact** code examples in your question, but a simple cast to `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<Bar>` will *not* be flagged as obsolete, nor will enumerating over it. In short, this won't solve all your problems.

Comment: @HCL If "many applications rely on the interface", marking it as obsolete is not going to cut it. You're looking at a **huge** change in your public API and you're going to want to document this a little better than marking something as obsolete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When implementing your interface, adding the `Obsolete` attribute on the `GetEnumerator` methods as shown below leads to your expectations :

```
public class MyClass : Foo
{
    public int SomethingNonObsolete
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    [Obsolete]
    public IEnumerator<Bar> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Obsolete]
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Result :

```
var c = new MyClass();

// Flagged as obsolete
foreach (var blah in c)
{

}

// Not flagged as obsolete
var s = c.SomethingNonObsolete;
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that, while this will prevent a direct `foreach` from succeeding without warning, it will do nothing to methods that take an `IEnumerable` (like `c.First())`, so the value of this as a way of detecting which consumers are using the `IEnumerable` implementation is limited.

Comment: True, but without trying to be nitpicky, it wasn't in the requirements :)

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted because it is constructive and solves one part of the question.

Comment: @HCL no it doesn't really, it gives you comfort while it shouldn't. Like Jeroen Mostert mentions, anyone who is using LINQ on your class will be in for a nasty surprise.

Comment: Yes, they must change their LINQ to the property which exposes the enumerable, what is more correct. As I said, certainly you are right, this is the reason why I will change the interface. My quesion however is not if I'm a poor coder or not, my question is specific if the declaration is possible or not.

Comment: @HCL maybe it is, but what Jeroen is saying, is that even if you somehow manage to get your `Obsolete` attributes right, LINQ consumers are *still* not going to notice.

Comment: You missunderstand. I dont say that I will go this way. I asked a question and the answer and the consequences for me were very clear. However, because the question was posted, it deserves an answer. Currently the answer is: It is not possible, and this is for a good reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ObsoleteAttribute` to mark a member as obsolete. Add it to each of your obsolete methods, and you'll get your warnings (or errors, depending on the arguments). However, this means you need to specify all the members - which is not possible in your case except on the instances implementing `Foo`. Your only other option is to mark the whole interface as obsolete, and replacing it with `Foo2` - in fact, this might be the best way to go about this anyway.

Also, note that this will only take care of direct invocations. The compiler has no way of knowing that `((IEnumerable<Bar>)yourFooInstance).GetEnumerator()` should be obsolete.

Comment: If I understand you right, it is not possible on the interface, however if I attribute the iterators of a concrete class, the foreach-call will be decorated with a compiler-warning?

Comment: @HCL Yes, because `foreach` cheats and doesn't use the `IEnumerable` interface at all. On the other hand, LINQ methods *do* use `IEnumerable\`1`, so they will not "see" your obsolete attributes at all.

Comment: It is perfectly legal to *hide* the `GetEnumerator()` and mark it with an attribute in the interface definition.  Use `new` keyword like so: `new IEnumerator<Bar> GetEnumerator();`

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting situation, but what you are going to do is a rather significant change to your API.

`Obsolete` is used mainly when you can *provide an alternative* instead, e.g. through XML doc (e.g. if you'd mark `SomethingNotObsolete` with `Obsolete` and say `use SomethingNew instead`.

The change you are going to make to your API will require code restructuring by your consumers and not simply replacing a method call. Therefore, you should reserve this for (ideally) a major release of your API and document a migration path for your consumers.

What I'm saying in one sentence is that `Obsolete` is not semantically correct in your situation.

Comment: Not sure if this is true. There are alternative ways of iterating over Bar (Over properties which return an Ienumerable<Bar>). The implementation of IEnumerable<Bar> was additional and only for convenience. However it showed, that its presence is not so pleasant.

Comment: You do not simply implement `IENumerable` in .NET "for convenience". It is *the* standard way of communicating that something can be iterated over. You're doing something wrong if you cannot implement it on anything that should be enumerable.

Comment: Thanks for the instruction, still the question reamains.

Comment: @HCL And my answer remains as well. There is a reason the .NET framework does not provide ways to mark extending or implementation of interfaces as Obsolete. You simply are changing a rather significant portion of your API surface. It doesn't only affect `foreach` but **anyone using any portion of LINQ** on your class as well, do you realise this? You're looking for a way to communicate this to your consumers, and I'm giving you one while steering you away from what you're looking at (wrongly).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new interface. Now within your new interface you do not inherit `IEnumerable` and make the original interface `Obsolete`. Now whoeever uses `foreach(Foo f in myFooImplementingInstance)` gets your obsolete-message. Ideally you would also add a hint that the new interface should be used instead. The basic idea is that your interface has a sole purpose. Changing its inheritance-chain or similar will crack the purpose in a highly un-predictable manner. So you should create a new interface which provides the the new requirements.

However I agree @MDeSchaepmeester that this is a major re-structuring that should be well documented. Doing this will have massively re-structuring of consumer-code and should therefor be planned and implemented with care.